# Como alterar Encoding padrão no Sublime Text 3

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, sublime-text, ascii, sublime-text-3

No meu trabalho, programamos em PHP principalmente e todos os arquivos de código foram feitos em ASCII, estou fazendo algumas inclusões de páginas e preciso muitas vezes abrir os arquivos existentes e adicionar novas coisas.

Faço isso através do Notepad++, pois sempre que abro um dos códigos existentes no Sublime, o mesmo muda o charset inteiro e buga toda a página.

Como mudo o charset do Sublime para abrir sempre o charset do arquivo? Ou mudar o charset padrão do sublime para sempre ASCII?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para mudar o `encoding` do `sublime`, vá em **Preferences>Settings**, pesquise por **`default_encoding`**, após isso coloque o parâmetro na área de configuração do usuário e indique o `encoding` desejado.

Outro item que pode ser útil no seu caso é tornar visível o `encoding` no `sublime`, para isso, também em **Preferences>Settings**, procure por **`show_encoding`**, coloque o parâmetro na área de configuração do usuário e mude o valor para `true`.

Abaixo segue algumas imagens:

**Abrindo as configurações:**

[image: Abrindo configurações]

**Default encoding:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mudando encoding:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Botão mostrar encoding:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Clicando no encoding:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acabei de testar, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado xD
Só uma outra dúvida na mesma linha, funcionaria essa alteração no VSCode também?

Comment: Fiz uma busca rápida aqui, vi que nas preferências dele tem opções de `encoding`, não fiz o teste para ver se funciona, hoje só consigo validar mais tarde. As configurações do VSCode ficam em **File>Preferences>Settings**, pesquise por `encoding`.

Comment: Acabei de testar e funcionou, "files.encoding", Muito Obrigado pela ajuda 0/

Comment: @LuisFelipe esse mesmo ^^ ;)